# Possible to send a PUT request to aws s3 presign url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, pre-signed-url

I've been trying to make use of the presign URL to put a file into my private S3 bucket.
But I kept receiving this error message

`<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>`

The presign URL was generated using this command

`aws s3 presign s3://<bucket-name>/<file-name> --expires-in 300`

But when I do a curl PUT request, the error occurred

`curl -T "<file-name>" "<Generated presign url>"`

Did some research saw people talking about adding the 'Content_Type' in the header when requesting for the presign URL, but the aws cli doesn't have that flag to include.

Is it possible to do a put request through aws cli??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS CLI doesn't support presigned PUT URL yet. You can easily generate one using Python Boto3 though. The documentation is [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=presigned#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url). If you want a presigned PUT, you just need to let `ClientMethod` param be `put_object`.